# Substituting client path on P4 sync

Tags: perforce

I have an XML file that refers to some other files. I can use neither relative paths nor variables in this file.

Is it possible to somehow add to the P4 repository a template and some script that will generate that file on the sync? E.g. I can use something trivial like sed to update paths depending on where the P4 client root is.

I really would like to make this transparent so I know that this file is always of proper version and contains actual info.

Comment: I tend to do this sort of thing as part of my build scripts, not as part of my 'p4 sync' operations. Make the first step in your build an invocation of some local tool that builds the desired generated file.

Comment: Build script is not an option as this file is needed for an IDE - so there is no reliable way to ensure the build is ran.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want dynamic root, try putting "null" (no quotes) in the root path of your workspace, and the root of your workspace will be whatever directory you are in.

If you are trying to create a dynamic workspace, you can create a text file of your workspace (p4 client -o > template_worksapce.txt) and use sed on that to create a workspace, then read it in via `p4 client -i`

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: What I am looking for is to change the file contents, e.g. "${client.root}/tools/mymodule" would become an absolute path, depending on the client root location.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
p4 info | grep 'Client root'
```

or:

```
p4 -ztag client -o | grep Root
```

Comment: But this should be ran manually - and I am looking for a way to push the change to the unsuspecting clients. Now that I mention it, it looks like this is not possible as it would be a huge security hole...

Comment: I have to admit I am unclear on what your goal is. I though you were trying to set an environment variable so that your XML processor could refer to a Perforce depot file by its absolute path in the workspace. But now it looks like maybe you want a way for Perforce to push a file into a user's workspace, without the user running 'p4 sync'. The only way to do the latter is to set up some kind of auto-sync service, like P4FTP, on the user's machine.